# Audio Unit Templates missing after upgrading to OSX Lion and XCode 4.6

Tags: xcode4.6

In previous versions of XCode, I was offered the option to choose to develop a New Audio Unit Effect Plugin and New Audio Unit Instrument in the New Project settings of XCode.

After updating to OSX Lion and updating to XCode 4.6, neither of those are options are available. How do I go about restoring these options or getting the templates? I also did an install of XCode 4.6 on another Mac with the same results.

Comment: Same here. Xcode 4.6, no template.